# Python selenium : Edit webpage source code

Tags: python, selenium

Here is my code :

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
opt.add_argument("start-maximized")
# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 2,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 2,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 2,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
    })

executable_path = r'C:\Users\SAMSUNG\Dropbox\CreationNumMaroc\chromedriver'
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path
global driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\SAMSUNG\Dropbox\CreationNumMaroc\chromedriver', options=opt)

# NavigationStart
time.sleep(3)
driver.get("https://yandex.com/")
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='input__control input__input mini-suggest__input']").send_keys("fkljdslkjdfdks")
time.sleep(2)
html_source = driver.page_source
if "fkljdslkjdfdks" in html_source:
    print(html_source)
else:
    print("nothing")
```

My script go to yandex.ru, write on search "fkljdslkjdfdks" .
and then :
I want to edit the word "fkljdslkjdfdks" from the source page .

Answer (score 0):

You have not clicked on search button and that is the reason you may not find searched string in page source.

Click on search button :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Search']/..").click()
```

**Update 1 :**

if you want to change the text then you would have to find the locator of that element. here is the sample code :

```
 element = driver.find_element_by_id("fkljdslkjdfdks id locator")
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'your new string value';", element)
```

Comment: and scripts get auto detected by web app. Not sure If you the code you have give can bypass it

Comment: My script print the source code, and i find the word i wrote on the printed source code. What i'm looking for is to change that word "fkljdslkjdfdks" on the source page

Comment: @addicted-python : check out the code in update 1 section and let me know if that works for you.